# Failed to find target with hash string 'android-23' - for IRANIAN user

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, react-native, jcenter

i know that is many other post with this title on Stackoverflow but i created this post because one of the most common problems for Iranian developer is this error (specially if you are starting with react native) and they are not answer for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason is sanctions against Iran and "jcenter.bintray.com" (the repository for downloading libraries) banned IPs from Iran. in "file ->setting->Appearance & Behavior->System Setting->Http Proxy" set a Http proxy or socks and rebuild project through "Build->Rebuild Project" in topbar. (you can find free socks with google searching) It's solved! now you see the message again just click on this link ->(( install missing platform(s) and sync project )) and download automatically the required SDK from the repo.

**UPDATE:**
the other way is that tunnel whole your pc by some program like softEther or openVpn.